# How to make user input text shift left if they type too many characters into input container

Tags: javascript, css, user-input

I want the field that users type in to shift left if they enter too many characters. How can I achieve this in css/javascript?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Comment: How do you define "too many characters"?

Comment: Such that they don't fit in the input container, like when you google search and enter a very long input, the text shifts left so the end and the text cursor are in view.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

JS:

```
let input = document.querySelector("#input");
input.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length > 5)
    input.setAttribute("style", "position:relative; margin-left: 100px;");
}
```

Comment: I meant like to give it a google search bar effect. In that case if you type in too many characters such that it won't fit in the search bar, the text shifts left so that the end is always in view. I don't think this achieves this

Comment: I see. So in that case it's the text IN the field you want to shift left? How about using a text area instead?